# How to change the color of tabs at runtime using WinForms?

Tags: c#, winforms, tabcontrol

Im a little new to C# and WinForms but what im essentially trying to do is have a set of tabs that have a colour status.

The program runs a set of tests ever x minutes so the status can change.

From what little I have been playing about, I can add a coloured rectangle in the tabs but I have no idea how or if I can change them?

Or is there a better alternative maybe? I'm tempted to use a tabless tab control and use labels to go between them as I know they are easier to change colour at runtime.

Does anyone know how to achieve the desired behavior?

Comment: Please provide a screenshot of what you actually want to do and show the relevant code you currently have.

Comment: Maybe this link will be helpfull:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2107463/is-there-a-way-to-color-tabs-of-a-tabpage-in-winforms