# How to change TabControl background color in c# winform

Tags: c#, winforms

How to change TabControl's background color in c# winform?
There is no available BackColor property in tab control class.
And the most of information is about tab page or tab button's back ground setting.
I make custom control class which is inherit to Winform.TabControl and i override 
protected override void OnPaintBackground() but it doesn't called.

Comment: You could set the background color of the tab pages, see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms160620(v=vs.110).aspx.

Comment: See as well https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2107463/is-there-a-way-to-color-tabs-of-a-tabpage-in-winforms and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5569284/how-do-i-change-background-colour-of-tab-control-in-winforms.

Comment: That is very much by design, the color is set by the user's preferred theme settings.  Older versions of Windows made them easier to change but they are still around.  Lots of colors of controls in the toolbox are theme selections, OpenFileDialog and MonthCalendar probably being the most obvious ones.  If you want something else for TabControl then you have to use the DrawMode property.

Comment: @Wollmich 감사하지만 내 질문에 대한 배경 색상입니다.